# How to rename 3rd party package name (webpack|vite) while packaging?

Tags: webpack, vite, rollup, esbuild

Currently my react project introduces a third-party library, such as the arco component library. When I am building a web project, I want to package the arco directory code under node_modules into a file with a specific name. For example, packaged into AKClown.js, how should I implement it?

Answer (score 0):

@arco-design package renamed to daopaas[hash].js

```
splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        cacheGroups: {
          arco: {
            name: 'daopaas',
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]@arco-design[\\/]/,
            priority: 6,
            chunks: 'initial'
          },
        },
      },
```

[image]

I only know this plan